# how to debug asynccallback method

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I mean for example AsyncGetter method.

```
req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" + city + "&hl=" + lang);
req.Method = "GET";
req.BeginGetResponse(AsyncGetter, req);
```

When I use F11 it doesn't enter this method.

Comment: What happens *after* this code?  If that exits the Main() method then your program will terminate before the response can be received.

Answer (score 1):

Place another breakpoint inside your asynchronous callback method, no need to press F11 at that moment (you can press F5 at that moment) and let that method execute, once you will get response it will fall to the breakpoint you set inside your callback method.

**Edit:**

```
req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(AsyncGetter), req);
```

AsyncGetter():

```
private void AsyncGetter(IAsyncResult result){
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Then most likely the problem is not with breakpoints but with server response, try specifying complete header details like `req.UserAgent`, `req.Accept` etc.

Comment: `req.Accept = null` `req.UserAgent threw not implemented exception`

Comment: I've got exactly such code in AsyncGetter `try
    {
     req = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
     resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(ar);
     sb = new StringBuilder();
    }`